# How do I embed a controller with a new scene in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I want to open a new scene with a controller but I get an IOException when I put the controller in it.
This is my method:

```
private void forgotAccount (ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
        Scene scene = stage.getScene();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Login.class.getResource("/mattiashellkvist/forgotAccount.fxml"));
        loader.setController(new ForgotAccountController());
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        scene.setRoot(root);
        stage.sizeToScene();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use e.printStackTrace instead of System.out.println, copy the entire stack trace and edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code is correct...please check your fxml location(which you provided to FXMLLoader) and fxml file for any error...and in catch use e.getMessage() to get detailed problem (i.e. System.out.println("Something went wrong "+e.getMessage());)

Comment: When I use getMessage it says: /C:/Users/Mattias/Documents/NetBeansProjects/login/target/classes/mattiashellkvist/forgotAccount.fxml

Comment: It was the full message... But so is it correct to put the controller in that method? It's a login page and when you click on 'forgot password' you come to a new scene where you can enter your email address. That's the scene I want to control, so that you can come to another scene after entering the address.

Comment: yup..your question is cleared to me.. i will still ask you to check for location which you are providing... and check your fxml for any error...this is what i can say by seeing this code.

Comment: I've checked, it takes me to the forgotAccount.fxml page if I don't put that controllerl there, so there can't be anything wrong with the fxml and the location too, right? Is there any other way around this?

Comment: You were right all the time. :) I had named the fx:id as cancelButtpn. Thanks!